# react js issue with rendering data in array.map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

laravel and react js

I am trying to getting data from laravel route and mapping it in my component when i try small code block under array.map function it works [link shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaD1m.png)  also saying that vision is unresolve variable, but it work and render the data

Now problem is here that when i try some big data under array.map it is making error  and not rendering layout problem code is here

```
  <div className="services-pack">

                            {
                                sr.map(data =>(
                            <div className="Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInRight slow">


                                <div className="icon-wrap">
                                    <div className="S-icon rounded-circle">
                                        <img  src="../../../img/fron-end.png" alt="icons fron-end"
                                             className="img-fluid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="S-name">
                                    <h3>{data.frontEnd}</h3>
                                    <p>{data.frontEnd-intro}</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>



                            <div className="Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInUp delay-1s slow">
                                <div className="icon-wrap">
                                    <div className="S-icon rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="../../../img/fron-end.png" alt="icons fron-end"
                                             className="img-fluid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="S-name">
                                    <h3>{data.backtEnd}</h3>
                                    <p>{data.backtEnd-intro}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div className="Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInUp delay-1s slow">
                                <div className="icon-wrap">
                                    <div className="S-icon rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="../../../img/fron-end.png" alt="icons fron-end"
                                             className="img-fluid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="S-name">
                                    <h3>Wordpress Website</h3>
                                    <p>Elementor & Visual Composer Dev. </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInUp delay-1s slower">
                                <div className="icon-wrap">
                                    <div className="S-icon rounded-circle">
                                        <img src="../../../img/fron-end.png" alt="icons fron-end"
                                             className="img-fluid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="S-name">
                                    <h3>Analytics</h3>
                                    <p>Get Insights Into Who Is Browsing Site</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                ) ) }



                                </div>
```

i want to render all my data in all of these Sr-items blocks, but when i shift closing brackets of map function at the end where i want to close them i makes error
[here how error code looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaD1m.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a JSX function can only return a single Element.

You need to wrap the returning elements of the function passed to the `map` with a React Fragment (https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
sr.map((data) => (
  <React.Fragment> // or just <>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    // ...
  </React.Fragment> // or just </>
))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are returning multiple div inside a single return statement when it should be only one.
Wrap all the div inside one parent div and it will work in the map return statement.

```
array.map(element => { return something;});
```

Or

```
array.map(element => something);
```

these two lines results are equal.
Also you cannot use hyphen(-) for variable names as you have used

```
<p>{data.frontEnd-intro}</p>
```

and

```
<p>{data.backtEnd-intro}</p>
```

Instead these should be:

```
<p>{data.frontEndIntro}</p>
```

Or

```
<p>{data.frontEnd_intro}</p>
```

and

```
<p>{data.backtEndIntro}</p>
```

Or

{data.backtEnd_intro}

Checkout this:

```
<div className='services-pack'>
        {this.state.sr.map((data) => (
          <div>
            <div className='Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInRight slow'>
              <div className='icon-wrap'>
                <div className='S-icon rounded-circle'>
                  <img
                    src='../../../img/fron-end.png'
                    alt='icons fron-end'
                    className='img-fluid'
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='S-name'>
                <h3>{data.frontEnd}</h3>
                <p>{data.frontEndIntro}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInUp delay-1s slow'>
              <div className='icon-wrap'>
                <div className='S-icon rounded-circle'>
                  <img
                    src='../../../img/fron-end.png'
                    alt='icons fron-end'
                    className='img-fluid'
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='S-name'>
                <h3>{data.backtEnd}</h3>
                <p>{data.backtEndIntro}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInUp delay-1s slow'>
              <div className='icon-wrap'>
                <div className='S-icon rounded-circle'>
                  <img
                    src='../../../img/fron-end.png'
                    alt='icons fron-end'
                    className='img-fluid'
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='S-name'>
                <h3>Wordpress Website</h3>
                <p>Elementor & Visual Composer Dev. </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='Sr-item z-depth-1 wow fadeInUp delay-1s slower'>
              <div className='icon-wrap'>
                <div className='S-icon rounded-circle'>
                  <img
                    src='../../../img/fron-end.png'
                    alt='icons fron-end'
                    className='img-fluid'
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='S-name'>
                <h3>Analytics</h3>
                <p>Get Insights Into Who Is Browsing Site</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```