# React Js data.map creating formatting issue with divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a Golf Scorecard that displays fine if I manually generate each row using divs but when I try and generate the divs in a data.map loop then it the formatting is all lost and doesnt display correctly.

Here is the code:

```
             <div className="griditem"></div>
          <div className="griditem">Total</div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem yellow">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem red">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem red">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem fred">
            <input type="text" className="input fred" />
          </div>
```

This is how I put it in the data.map:

```
         {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div className="griditem"></div>
          <div className="griditem">Total</div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem yellow">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem red">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem red">
            <input type="text" className="input" />
          </div>
          <div className="griditem fred">
            <input type="text" className="input fred" />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

[How the formatting should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CzRw.png)

[how the formatting appears in a data.map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZCll.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the resulting HTML is different.  In the second example you're wrapping all of the elements in an outer `<div>` which isn't present in the first example:

```
{data.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    {...}
  </div>
)}
```

If your styling is targeting a specific structure, changing that structure will break that styling.  Either update the styling, or don't change the structure.  You can wrap your elements in a React fragment instead:

```
{data.map((item, index) => (
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    {...}
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

Comment: If i hadnt put the original in a <div key={index}> originally I got an error.  How would I update the styling above rather than using React.Fragment?

Comment: @mvarta: However your styling is defined, you'd change it to match the new structure.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer eventually from here --> [react js issue with rendering data in array.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065097/react-js-issue-with-rendering-data-in-array-map)

```
 {data.map((item, index) => (
 <React.Fragment>
  </React.Fragment>
      ))}
```